# Unbind some event handlers with namespaces

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to ask, how can I remove event handlers from the `document`, but only those with a namespace?

I have this piece of code, I see no errors, but this function always fires the event handlers for `mouseup` and `touchend` even after `.unbind`. I'm sure that I have some errors in this code.

```
$(".inp").on("autocompleteresponse", function(event, ui) {
    $(document).bind( "mouseup.test, touchend.test", function(e) {
        var container = $('.ui-autocomplete');
        if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
            if (ui.content.length > 0) {
                ui.item = ui.content[0];
                console.log (ui.item);
                $(".inp").val(ui.item.label);
                // This will fire always, on document click, should only once per time
                $(document).unbind("mouseup.test, touchend.test");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks for advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `on()` and `off()` are now the preferred methods instead of the outdated `bind()` and `unbind()`.

Secondly, to fix your issue you should separate the events with a space, not a comma. Try this:

```
$(".inp").on("autocompleteresponse", function(event, ui) {
    $(document).on("mouseup.test touchend.test", function(e) {
        var container = $('.ui-autocomplete');
        if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
            if (ui.content.length > 0) {
                ui.item = ui.content[0];
                console.log(ui.item);
                $(".inp").val(ui.item.label);

                $(document).off("mouseup.test touchend.test");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Also note that if you want to turn off all events associated with a namespace you can pass the namespace alone to the `off()` method:

```
$(document).off(".test")
```